# How to change size of viewpager to match the screen and not overlap with other elements?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to make a simple layout for my app, I used Relative Layout to put the TabLayout to bottom but now another issue occurred I can't properly resize the viewpager.
Here is the look of my layout and what I want to achieve:
[LOOK of the layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viu91.png)
Here is my XML code for the activity:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/near_white"
        app:tabBackground="@color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Subhead.Bold"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/grey_20" />
    //
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this :

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/tab_layout"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/near_white"
                app:tabBackground="@color/white"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Subhead.Bold"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/grey_20" />
        //
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/near_white"
        app:tabBackground="@color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Subhead.Bold"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/grey_20" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I wish, this will be helpful..

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work properly the viewpager was cut out, the other answer fixed that